# .htaccess rewrite not working with image links

Tags: html, angularjs, apache, .htaccess, angular-ui-router

I want all redirects to index.html except for files.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

When I click on a link that ends with an image, instead of a redirect to index.html, I want that image to open. My image link path is correct, if I do right click and open link, image opens. But when I click on image the page redirects to index.html

```
<a ng-href="{{$ctrl.photo.photo_large}}"><img ng-src="{{$ctrl.photo.photo_normal}}"></a>
```